# Filter document by element attributes using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this XML document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<teryt>
<catalog name="TERC" type="all" date="2010-01-01">
<row>
  <field name="Woj">1</field>
  <field name="City">Warszawa</field>
  <field name="Name">Mazowsze</field>
</row>
<row>
  <field name="WojId">1</field>
  <field name="City"/>
  <field name="Name">Mazowsze</field>
</row>
<row>
  <field name="Woj">2</field>
  <field name="City"/>
  <field name="Name">Slask</field>
</row>
</catalog>
</teryt>
```

And now I want to get only rows which don't have value in field with attribute City (using LINQ to XML).

Comment: Your XML is not valid. There's no start tag for rows and the second City tag is not closed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like:

```
var rows = from row in doc.Root.Elements("rows")
           where !row.Elements("field")
                     .Any(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "City"
                               && x.Value != "")
           select row;
```

That says, "find all rows which don't have any non-empty `field` elements with a `name` attribute of `City`". I *think* that's what you're after...

Comment: with a <field name="City"/> the x.Value will be null, not "", won't it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var query = from row in xdoc.Descendants("row")
            where row.Elements("field")
                     .Any(ff => ff.Attribute("name").Value == "City"
                             && String.IsNullOrWhitespace(ff.Value))
            select row;
```

*This is predicated on the desire to find every row without a City value.*

Answer (score 1):

Once you have loaded your xml document into an XDocument object you can access its tags. So you should grab the Root element of your XDocument and navigate down to the row tags with the Elements method. And when you have all your tags in a collection you can sort out the ones with no city field. I'm almost sure that there is a HasValue property on the xml elements which tells you if it has value or not. But if there isn't one, you can check the Value property which would be empty or null.

So now a little code for this, the way I like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("yourfile");
var tags = doc.Root.Element("catalog")
                   .Elements("row")
                   .Where(r=>r.Elements("field")
                       .Single(f=>f.Attribute("name").Value == "City" 
                             && string.IsNullOrWhitespace(f.Value)));
```

It translates into something like this: *Take the document, select the root of the document, take the element named "catalog", and give me all the "row" elements, where it is true, that if the "row" has a "field" element with the "name" attribute set to "City", it is null, empty string, or whitespace.*

Now this may not be so easy to understand if you are new to this, but this is the way I would do it. You may add a few null-checks but this is up to you now.

Comment: this will return the `<field>` elements rather than the `<row>` elements. From my understanding of the OP's question (which may be wrong) he wants the `<row>` elements.

Comment: Also `Single` will throw an exception if there is not exactly 1 element matching the predicate.

Comment: That is also true, but it seems like field tags, name attributes and the City attribute value is present all tags, so it may as well be required. And if it is, Single won't be a propblem. Of corse you can can always use SingelOrDefault, but then you'll have to deal with the option of it returning null.